# How do I Print file to default printer without user interaction or charms in windows store application 8.1 for kiosk?

Tags: c#, printing, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I am new to windows store application. I am developing application for Kiosk Machine which supports print feature.
I am downloading a PDF file & I can able to Launch file via Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync() method. With the help of charms I can able to print the file.

However I want to print this file without any user interaction. 
Are there any API's available to print file without user interaction ?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Mohsin

Comment: I want to print this file in background without any user interaction.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/25/creating-a-great-printing-experience-in-windows-8.aspx ?